# Change server date using PHP

Tags: date

Is this possible to change Linux server date using php code?

Is there any way to give necessary permissions to Apache to do this?

What is the procedure to give root permissions to Apache?

Comment: Why would you give Apache root permissions anyway?

Comment: I dont want to give root permission to apache but necessary permissions for apache to change the date.

Comment: While that may be possible, I wouldn't recommend it. Setting the date manually on a network-connected computer is highly unusual: normally it is set automatically by [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with sudo, without giving "root" permissions to apache.

```
apache <hostname> = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/date
```

Which in English translates roughly to:

> Let the apache user run the `/bin/date` command as the root user without requiring a password on server `<hostname>`.

Using sudo, (or doing the equivalent in any RBAC model) allows you to expose only the privileges you need to, to specific users, to accomplish your goals.

Then in PHP, just pass the sudo in along with the command:

```
exec("sudo -su /bin/date <newdate>");
```

Also, if that's not working for you, check your `/etc/sudoers` file for `requiretty`:

```
Defaults        requiretty
```

You'll need to comment that out, for sudo to work with apache.

Comment: If you're running a system with SELinux (and if you're running a web server that has PHP on it, you **really** should be using SELinux), I bet you'll get an SELinux denial if php tries to exec sudo.

Comment: if you are using SELinux, you may need to use `audit2allow` to parse selinux audit logs and system logs to create the appropriate rules for SELinux.  see http://www.thedumbterminal.co.uk/php/knowledgebase/article/131 for an example.